# Functionality to edit Word (.docx) file on Phonegap IOS/Android App?

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, cordova

My phonegap app needs the functionality to download a docx file edit it and upload it back.

I can download the file using file-transfer plugin, and then open/edit it with MSWord on ios with File-opener plugin, but can't find a way to find the edited file on the file system to upload it back

MSWord or Pages app on ios does not edit the source file but instead makes a copy of it when opened with fileopener.

I am using Phonegap 3.6 and Rails backend

Comment: You can't, unless you create a plugin to edit docx. But you can try to edit it online on google docs, using inAppBrowser like this: window.open('https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.example.com/example.docx&embedded=true', '_blank');

Comment: is it possible to access files in word/pages app from phonegap app?

Comment: Maybe with a plugin, and just on iOS 8

Comment: Can you ask you users to "share" the file back to your application?

Comment: How to share the file back to the application?